# JAAS additional LoginModules

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jaas

I'd like to know how to combine these two authentication steps :

1. check the user/password in an LDAP
2. add principals (roles) found in a DB to the subject.

The LDAP user repository have no idea about application-specific roles and I don't want to manage the passwords in the application DB. So I need both.

JAAS configuration file allows to have additional LoginModules :

```
<name used by application to refer to this entry> { 
    <LoginModule> <flag> <LoginModule options>;
    <optional additional LoginModules, flags and options>;
};
```

but I can't find example that explains how I works.

Is it the good method ?

Thanks

=========================================

Here is my answer :

Indeed we can have additional LoginModules. The JAAS configuration file is :

```
Sample {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule Requisite
  userProvider="ldap://acme.org:389/OU=Users,OU=_ACME,DC=acmegis,DC=acme,DC=org"
  authIdentity="{USERNAME}"
  userFilter="(userPrincipalName={USERNAME})"
  storePass=true

  sample.module.SampleLoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

Here we have two LoginModules :

The Sun's LdapLoginModule that checks user/password,
and mine sample.module.SampleLoginModule that query my db and fills the principals.
The important parameter is storePass=true that asks the LdapLoginModule to store the username and password in the module's shared state. (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/LdapLoginModule.html).

So the next LoginModules can get the username passed to the initialize method in the sharedState Map argument. They should have nothing to do in login() and the query in DB to fill the Principales is done in commit() (like Shimi Bandiel said).

I don't use it yet but there is a DatabaseServerLoginModule developed by JBoss (see http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabaseServerLoginModule) that supports authentication and role mapping. Used with password-stacking=useFirstPass we should have the answer to my need without write any line-code (but a beautiful JAAS configuration file).

B.R.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a `LoginModule` which in the `login` method you access the LDAP and check username/password and in the `commit` method you access the DB and fill the principals.
There is no need here to use multiple `LoginModule`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But "com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule" already checks for the user/password via LDAP, I don't want to rewrite it. Have a look to my answer and let a comment (if you want). B.R.

Answer (score 0):

It is great!
But implement the LoginModule give you more power to customize the way you interact with LDAP server.
I also struggle the same problem as you.
But remember when implement the LoginModule, you should **add the role in login() function , not in commit()**, otherwise your subjet will not get the principal.