# JAAS configuration and LDAP login module in JavaEE 6

Tags: java, ldap, glassfish-3, java-ee-6, jaas

I'm writing a question here because I haven't been able to find the solution myself for months. My situation: I have a client-server application written on java which uses Java2ee 6 and EJB3.0. The server side is deployed on the glassfish 3.0. I need to develop/implement the login module for application. Authentification must be done using ldap server and authorisation will be handled inside application. Therefore I want to hire JAAS technology to mix authentification and authorisation. I'm doing it for example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414322/jaas-additional-loginmodules). Then I follow [this tutorial](http://www.devx.com/security/Article/28849/0/page/3) and [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/LdapLoginModule.html) to perform login. My problem is that ldap login doesn't work.

My code:

```
    LoginContext lc = null;

    try {
        CallbackHandler handler = new CallbackHandler() {
            public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws UnsupportedCallbackException {
                for( int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++ ) {
                    if( callbacks[i] instanceof NameCallback ) {
                        // prompt the user for a username
                          NameCallback nc = (NameCallback)callbacks[i];
                          nc.setName("admin");
                          System.out.println("Login done.");
                    } else if( callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback ) {
                        // prompt the user for sensitive information
                          PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback)callbacks[i];
                          pc.setPassword("mypassword".toCharArray());
                          System.out.println("Password done.");
                    } else {
                        throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i], "Unrecognized Callback");
                    } //end if/else
                } //end for()
            }
        };

        lc = new LoginContext("myAuth", handler);
        lc.login();
        Subject subject = lc.getSubject();
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My JAAS configuration file:

```
myAuth {
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LDAPLoginModule REQUIRED
userProvider="ldap://mydomain:389/OU=users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"
authIdentity="{USERNAME}"
    useSSL=false
debug=true;
};
```

The client part of application is run with the following jvm options:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./jaas.conf  -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost
```

On the glassfish site I set the jvm properties

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/login.conf
-Djava.naming.referral=follow
```

The login.conf file on the glassfish side contains the following lines (ADRealm is the default realm of my glassfish)

```
ADRealm {
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LDAPLoginModule REQUIRED;
};
```

Settings for ADRealm:

```
      <property name="jaas-context" value="ldapRealm" />
      <property name="base-dn" value="CN=users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" />
      <property name="directory" value="ldap://mydomain:3268" />
      <property name="search-bind-password" value="mypassword" />
      <property name="search-bind-dn" value="admin@my.domain.com" />
```

I want to stress your attention that I'm trying to perform ldap login at least to be sure that it works.

When I run the client I get the following error:

```
Mar 1, 2013 1:36:44 PM com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule extractCredentials
SEVERE: passwordlm.nopwdcred
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No credentials.
```

What is strange that is worked once(!), i.e. I could obtain `subject` from `lc.getSubject()` method. Also I assume that `handle()` method above is not invoked since I don't see

```
Login done.
Password done.
```

in the output.

Please could anybody help me???

Comment: Take a good look at [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147) to get the grasp of JAAS authentication.

Comment: See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/LdapLoginModule.html :
"authIdentity=auth_id
This option specifies the identity to use when authenticating a user to the LDAP directory... Note that if this option does not contain a distinguished name then the userFilter option must also be specified."
Did you try adding the userFilter option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st - On LDAP you don't use an admin user, but create another user with necessary criteria to search and/or bind if necessary. An admin user isn't secure and not recommended, especially in a Java EE context.

2nd - What kind of LDAP server do you try to connect to? OpenLDAP or an Exchange server?

I'm referring you to these links, while waiting for your response:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASLMDevGuide.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html

Comment: Thank you for reply, @Giorgio! Regarding your 2nd question I'm using Active Directory, a part of Win server 2003 R2. I have already read that documentation but I will do it once more carefully.
And by the way I rejected the idea to use JAAS tools, because I had not much time. Instead I employed `InitialLdapContext` on the server side.

Comment: Hi, thanks for informations. With Active Directory W2003 R2, create a user associated by 'SchemaAdmin' group.